# How do something when call rejected by person?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want do something when call rejected by person and by red button.
i know below permition and code in manifest

```
<receiver android:name="Call_Receiver">
        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
```

But How to Write `Call_Receiver.java`

Comment: You should check out google. There are quite a few good tutorials and examples on how to write broadcast receivers.

Comment: @Qberticus I checked it but i dont found thing that i want it.